# Git Maintain base project

Tags: git, version-control

In our company we plan on having a base project. Every other web app we will make will include this base project as a sort of a "starter package". It's a core of essential features that will be included in every project we make in the future.

The idea is that this core project will be actively maintained: there will be bug fixes made into the core and new features can constantly be added. Each change in the core project should reflect on every project based on this project (either automatically or manually).

Do you know of any way we can maintain this? I've tried Googling this, but seem to be using the wrong keywords to find anything relevant.

I've thought of having a Git repository containing the base project and implement every project based on the core as a seperate branch. I could then push my changes to the core, and merge to every sub-branch. This however does not seem ideal to me.

I've also found an explanation of Git submodules, and this seems very interesting (http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), but I don't know if this can be used in the way I want it to. For example, what if, for my current project I have to change something fundamental in the core project. I don't want to do this change for every project based on the core project but only for my current project. Is this even possible?

How do you go about this? Does anyone have any experience in this field? Can anyone please point us in the right direction?

Comment: You could use git submodules, but it gets kind of messy (every update to the submodule is a change in your main repository). The language you're developping in probably has a package manager of some sort : npm for node, composer for php, maven for java, nuget for C#, go get for go. Can't you use one of them ?

Comment: Hello: we hadn't considered using Nuget yet, but this may indeed be ideal. Thank you for the suggestion!